# Какая бывает библиотека для "отлова" нажатия клавиш клавиатуры в линуксе?

Tags: linux, c, gcc

Мне требуется отловить нажатие клавиши на клавиатуре.

Нажатие кнопки ввода проблемы нету.

А вот нажатие допустим иной кнопки(кроме ввода) и последующей реакции системы, увы не знаю .

В виндувсе можно включить библиотеку работающую с `winAPI` а вот в линуксе не знаю что делать. В основном догадываюсь что надо работать с `POSIX`, а вот как не знаю. Слышал об `#include <curses.h>` но qtCreator не видит такой заголовочный файл.

Какая бывает библиотека для "отлова" нажатия клавиш клавиатуры в линуксе ?

Comment: Какой именно отлов вас интересует? Отлов событий клавиатуры в активном графическом окне? Отлов стандартного ввода в текущем терминале? Отлов всех событий устройства независимо от текущего окна/терминала? Что если к компьютеру подключено несколько клавиатур? Должны ли учитываться виртуальные клавиатуры и ввод через удалённые подключения (vnc, ssh)?

Comment: *termios* — базовая библиотека для работы с терминалом. Конкретно про Linux все действитя идут через специальные устройства ввода */dev/input/*. Вот, подписавшсь на события там, можно выудить нажатия клавиш конкретного устройства (на компьютере может быть много клавиатур).

Answer (score 1):

Слышали вы правильно, вам нужно установить `ncurses-dev` или `ncurses-devel` - от дистрибутива зависит. Тогда и файл появится.